# Suggest the xpath to check the first 'text' node within nested elements of same type

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt-2.0

Please suggest the xpath to check, whether element 'mo' is preceded by 'text node' within first child of 'mfrac'. Present XSLT code is running successfully for all 'mfrac's where those should not nested within one more 'mfrac' (math 1 and 2 are running successfully, but Math 3 is not). If 'mfrac's are nested by one more 'mfrac's then some error messgae is occuring. Required out put put is 'mo' should get attribute 'form=prefix', if 'mo' is not having preceded text node within 'mfrac/child::*' ('mo' as first text node). Please suggest how to avoid the error message. Ignore the comments which are placed in result text.

**XML:**

```
<article>
<body>
    <p>
        <math id="eq1"><mi>i</mi>
            <mfrac>
                <mrow><mo>+</mo></mrow>
                <mrow><mi>t</mi></mrow>
            </mfrac>
        </math>
        <math id="eq2">
            <mfrac>
                <mrow><mi>i</mi><mo>+</mo></mrow>
                <mrow><mi>t</mi></mrow>
            </mfrac>
        </math>

        <math id="eq3"><mi>i</mi><mfrac><mrow><mfrac><mo>+</mo><mi>n</mi></mfrac></mrow><mrow><mi>t</mi></mrow></mfrac></math>
    </p>
</body>
</article>
```

**XSLT:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="mo">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="string-length(preceding::text()[1]
                  [normalize-space(.)!='']
                  [generate-id(ancestor-or-self::*[count(preceding-sibling::*)=0]/parent::*[name()='mfrac'])=generate-id(current()/ancestor-or-self::*[count(preceding-sibling::*)=0]/parent::*[name()='mfrac'])]) eq 0">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="form" select="'prefix'"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>

</xsl:template>
```

**Required output:**

```
<article>
<body>
    <p>
        <mmlmath id="eq1"><mi>i</mi>
            <mfrac>
                <mrow><mo form="prefix">+</mo></mrow><!--Here prefix attribute required because MO found as first text node within MFRAC's first child-->
                <mrow><mi>t</mi></mrow>
            </mfrac>
        </mmlmath>
        <mmlmath id="eq2">
            <mfrac>
                <mrow><mi>i</mi><mo>+</mo></mrow><!--Here attribute not required because 'MO' is not a first text node-->
                <mrow><mi>t</mi></mrow>
            </mfrac>
        </mmlmath>

        <mmlmath id="eq3"><mi>i</mi><mfrac><mrow><mfrac><!--Nested MFRAC--><mo form="prefix">+</mo><!--Attribute required here--><mi>n</mi></mfrac></mrow><mrow><mi>t</mi></mrow></mfrac></mmlmath>
    </p>
</body>
</article>
```

Error message:

```
XPTY0004: A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of  generate-id() (<mfrac/>, <mfrac/>)
```

Comment: Which error message exactly do you get from which XSLT processor? I used your input sample and the XSLT (after adding a closing `</xsl:stylesheet>`) and I don't get any error message. Also I don't see any `mo` in `<math id="eq3"><mi>i</mi><mfrac><mrow></mrow><mrow><mi>t</mi></mrow></mfrac></math>`, so why does the wanted output have one?

Comment: Ditto what Martin said. You would save a lot of time by stating what the error message is, instead of just saying "some error message is occurring." Also please show in your sample a case where  "`mfrac`s are nested by one more `mfrac`s".

Comment: Sorry for my not detailed information, now I have updated the input xml and error message I placed. Please suggest. I am using Saxon9he.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to test to see if the current `mo` is the first descendant of the first ancestor `mfrac` that contains a `text()` node.

Hopefully that makes sense. :-)

Here's an example that should help...

**XML Input**

```
<article>
    <body>
        <p>
            <math id="eq1">
                <mi>i</mi>
                <mfrac>
                    <mrow>
                        <mo>+</mo>
                    </mrow>
                    <mrow>
                        <mi>t</mi>
                    </mrow>
                </mfrac>
            </math>
            <math id="eq2">
                <mfrac>
                    <mrow>
                        <mi>i</mi>
                        <mo>+</mo>
                    </mrow>
                    <mrow>
                        <mi>t</mi>
                    </mrow>
                </mfrac>
            </math>
            <math id="eq3">
                <mi>i</mi>
                <mfrac>
                    <mrow>
                        <mfrac>
                            <mo>+</mo>
                            <mi>n</mi>
                        </mfrac>
                    </mrow>
                    <mrow>
                        <mi>t</mi>
                    </mrow>
                </mfrac>
            </math>
        </p>
    </body>
</article>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="mo[. is (ancestor::mfrac[1]//*[text()])[1]]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="form" select="'prefix'"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<article>
   <body>
      <p>
         <math id="eq1">
            <mi>i</mi>
            <mfrac>
               <mrow>
                  <mo form="prefix">+</mo>
               </mrow>
               <mrow>
                  <mi>t</mi>
               </mrow>
            </mfrac>
         </math>
         <math id="eq2">
            <mfrac>
               <mrow>
                  <mi>i</mi>
                  <mo>+</mo>
               </mrow>
               <mrow>
                  <mi>t</mi>
               </mrow>
            </mfrac>
         </math>
         <math id="eq3">
            <mi>i</mi>
            <mfrac>
               <mrow>
                  <mfrac>
                     <mo form="prefix">+</mo>
                     <mi>n</mi>
                  </mfrac>
               </mrow>
               <mrow>
                  <mi>t</mi>
               </mrow>
            </mfrac>
         </math>
      </p>
   </body>
</article>
```

Comment: +1, good answer. I'm thinking it would be more robust to elaborate `[text()]` with a test to ensure it's not a whitespace-only text node... e.g. `[text()[normalize-space()]]`. But maybe that's not necessary because of your `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>`?

Comment: @LarsH - Yeah `xsl:strip-space` should take care of that, but you have a good point and that's a detail a lot of visitors might miss. I was thinking though that it should be possible to replace `[text()]` with `[normalize-space()]`, but testing with Saxon 9.5.1 it does appear that the predicate needs to be added to `text()`. That seems strange to me. I don't think I've ever done that. I'm pretty sure I've always been able to just swap `text()` with `normalize-space()`. (It works fine with a simple match: http://xsltransform.net/eiZQaGj)

Comment: I would have expected `[normalize-space()]` without `[text()]` to work as well. The reason I didn't use it is that it could require computing the recursive string value of each element descendant of `mfrac`, which seems needlessly inefficient.

Comment: `.//*[text()[normalize-space()]` looks for elements having a non-whitespace text node child, while  `.//*[normalize-space()]` looks (in effect) for elements having a non-whitespace text node descendant. Not the same thing.